# Не запускается сервер

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, vue.js

Нашел код в интернете похожий на то что мне надо сделать, но он почему-то не запускается.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина.

[image: index.html]

[image: index.js]

[image: package.json][image: style.css]

Текст ошибки:

```
user1@User1:~/Рабочий стол/vue$ npm run test
npm ERR! missing script: test

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user1/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T07_28_22_896Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить свой скрипт запуска в файл **package.json**

```
"start": "node index",
```

Или просто запусти командой

```
node index
```